# get relation in laravel if foreign_id is not null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wonder if is there any method in Laravel that check if `column_id` is not null and contains a valid id, then bring the relation if It is ?

so for example:
instead of doing this:

```php
if ($order->billing_address_id && $billingAddress = $order->billingAddresses){
```

how can I just type something like this:

```php
$billingAddress = $order->getRelation('billingAddresses') // check the column_id first
```

- note:
  the original `$order->billingAddresses` runs the join sql without check the column_id if its null first

Comment: It thinks what your looking for is `has()` method ? Like `Order::has('bilingAddress')->get();` Check it here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @xenooooo , `has()` method checks & retrieves orders that only HAS billingAddresses, and i want all orders

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're misunderstanding the relation. Your `$order->billing_address_id` (a single integer column) can only point to a single relation. The `orders` table holds the reference to the `billingAddress` relation in this case.

However, you are retrieving `$order->billingAddresses` (a `hasMany` relation) which means in order to know if there are any `billingAddresses`, you have to check the FOREIGN table `billing_addresses` since that (probably) holds a column named `order_id`.

In the first case you can simply see in the order object itself if you should retrieve a billingAddress by checking the local key (Laravel automagically sees this and doesn't run a query if local key = null). In the second case, you MUST check the foreign table so there will always run a query.

Comment: Are you sure ? If I'm not wrong it will still execute the query but it will give you a null in the relationship

Comment: Why would it execute the query if there is nothing to retrieve? You can call `$order->billingAddress` and it will return `null` immediately without running a query if there is no local key.

Comment: @A.El-zahaby I've rewritten the answer. You seem to be confusing 2 types of relations. I also read it wrongly the first time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$billingAddress = $order->when($order->billing_address_id, function (Builder $query) use ($order) {
    return $query->relationLoaded('billingAddresses') ? $order->billingAddresses : $query;
});
```

You can conditionally retrieve the relation if the column `billing_address_id`  is not null and the relation NOT has already been loaded.

P.S: it assumes relation defined b/w `Order` and `BillingAddress` models.